# slf4j-logj12.jar concurrents with log4j-over-slf4j.jar of other Webapp on Tomcat6

Tags: tomcat6, jira

I want to run Jira on the same Tomcat6 as an other Webapp, that needs log4j-over-slf4j.jar.

As described in https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Installing+JIRA+on+Tomcat+6.0+or+7.0 I had to copy the .jar library files from an archive to the lib subdirectory of your Tomcat installation directory. This archive implements the slf4j-logj12.jar.

When I try to start the other Webapp it failed because of log4j-over-slf4j.jar and slf4j-logj12.jar cannot be present simultaneously.

Is it possible to tell jira to use the slf4j-logj12.jar in his own lib subdirectory instead of Tomcat's?

Using Jira 5.2 and Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to put the log4j-over-slf4j.jar in the WEB-INF/lib/endorsed folder. This way it should override the the information in catalina_home/lib.

Make sure to redeploy Webapp after these changes.